# Compactness preserved in subspace

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $A,B$ are topological spaces, $B $ is a subspace of $A $ and  $X\subseteq B $.

If $X $ is compact in $ A$ then is $X $ compact in B?

If an open covering of $X$ in $B$ is in fact an open covering in $A$ then by compactness of $A$ we would have a finite sub covering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and you can prove it directly from the definitions.  You are assuming we have a chain of subspaces $X \subseteq B \subseteq A$.  If $\{O_\beta \mid \beta \in I\}$ is an open cover of $X$ in $B$, then $O_\beta = B \cap U_\beta$ where $U_\beta$ is open in $A$.  Then $\{U_\beta \mid \beta \in I\}$ is an open cover of $X$ in $A$, so this would reduce finitely by compactness.  Now use the same finite number of $U_\beta$'s to create a finite number of $O_\beta$'s derived from the original cover.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\bigcup U_{i \in I} \supset X$ be a finite covering of $X$ in $A$.  Since $B$ is a subspace of $A$ then $\tau_B = \{B \bigcap U | U \in \tau\}$.  This proves that there is a finite covering of $X$ in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X$ is compact relative to $A$  and let $ \{O\}_i$ be collection of open sets relative to $B$, such that $X\subset \bigcup_i O_i$.
By definition of subspace topology,
there exists $N_i$ open in $A$, such that $O_i=B\cap N_i$, for all $i$. Since $X$ is compact in $A$.
Therefore,
$$X\subset N_{i_1}\cup\dots \cup N_{i_k}$$ for some choice of finitely many indices $i_1,\dots,i_k$.

Since $X\subset B$, $\Longrightarrow$
$X\subset O_{i_1}\cup\dots \cup O_{i_k}$.